# Sql Query Notification With aggregate function SUM

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Good day,

I am using one of the powerful functionality in SQL which is Sql Query Notification..
I' tried  it and it works great but when i already use aggregate function Sum, i got error saying that
**

> "INVOKE OR BEGIN CANNOT BE CALLED ON A CONTROL UNTIL THE WINDOW HANDLE
> HAS BEEN CREATED"..

#### C#

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) { 
    try { 
        UIDelegate uidel = new UIDelegate(RefreshData); 
        this.Invoke(uidel, null); 
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender; 
        dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange; } 
    catch (Exception R) { 
        MessageBox.Show(R.Message); 
    } 
}
```

What I know about this is that the error was came from my query which uses Aggregate Function Sum that's why .

How to use Aggregate function SUM in SQL QUERY NOTIFICATION ?
here is my query form kindly check it .. I am 100% sure that the problem is in my query.. please
help..
thank you :)

#### SQL

```
SELECT SALES_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID AS [SALES ORDER ID],
       CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME     AS [CUSTOMER NAME],
       SALES_ORDER.OrderDate,
       SALES_ORDER.ORDERSTATUS    AS [STATUS],
       SUM(ORDERLINE.AMOUNT)      AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM   dbo.SALES_ORDER
       INNER JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER
         ON dbo.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = dbo.SALES_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.ORDERLINE
         ON dbo.ORDERLINE.SALES_ORDER_ID = dbo.SALES_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID
WHERE  dbo.SALES_ORDER.ORDERSTATUS = 'PENDING'
        OR dbo.SALES_ORDER.ORDERSTATUS = 'COMPLETED'
        OR dbo.SALES_ORDER.ORDERSTATUS = 'PROVISIONING'
           AND dbo.ORDERLINE.OrderLineStatus = 'PENDING'
        OR dbo.ORDERLINE.OrderLineStatus = 'COMPLETED'
        OR dbo.ORDERLINE.OrderLineStatus = 'PROVISIONING'
GROUP  BY dbo.SALES_ORDER.SALES_ORDER_ID,
          dbo.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME,
          dbo.SALES_ORDER.OrderDate,
          dbo.SALES_ORDER.ORDERSTATUS
ORDER  BY [SALES ORDER ID] DESC
```

Comment: this is the C# code and the error is thrown is came from the 
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                UIDelegate uidel = new UIDelegate(RefreshData);
                this.Invoke(uidel, null);
                SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
                dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
            }
            catch (Exception R)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(R.Message);
            }
        }